# getting messages from telegram channels - python

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

i want to develop a bot in telegram with python.
i don't know [getUpdates](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api/#getupdates) can help me or not? or there is any method for doing it.
i want to get information(text,pic,link...) of messages from telegram channels.
i don't want to do any function inside channels(edit, new post...) so i don't have to be admin of channels.
actually i found a bot that can do this(@junction_bot) but i can`t found out how!!??
what syntax i should use?
i tried [getUpdates](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api/#getupdates) method, it should work?

Answer (score 0):

Your bot need Channel Administrator permission to receive messages, and you will get `channel_post` in update, not `message`

Comment: i found out this bot @junction_bot doing this without permission of admin, you just forward a post from a channel to it and bot send you all new messages postet in that channel.

Comment: @Sean Wei are you sure that the bot needs admin permission? Do you have any reference for this?

Answer (score 0):

Url : `https://api.telegram.org/bot<TOKEN>/getUpdates`

Example on python for get last chat_id and message

```
URL = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' + token + '/'
global last_update_id
last_update_id = 0

def get_updates():
    url = URL + 'getupdates'
    r = requests.get(url)
    return r.json()

def get_message():
    data = get_updates()

    last_object = data['result'][-1]
    current_update_id = last_object['update_id']

    global last_update_id
    if last_update_id != current_update_id:
        last_update_id = current_update_id

        chat_id = last_object['message']['chat']['id']
        message_text = last_object['message']['text']
        message = {
        'chat_id': chat_id, 
        'text': message_text
                }   
        return message['chat_id'], message['text']
    return '0', '0'
```

also u can formate a json dump and take data from updates.json

```
def format_json_dump():
    data = get_updates()
    with open('updates.json', 'w+') as file:
        json.dump(data, file, indent = 2, ensure_ascii=False)
```